# Jenkins parameter is getting replaced by a white space

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, cygwin

I have a parameterized build (copied from an existing job) in Jenkins. While building, my parameter is getting replaced by a white space. Here I am sharing what I have.

Parameter Name: `BuildDate` (I tried using `%%` and `${}` but no luck)

Windows batch command:

```
copy \\Network_drive\dir1\dir2\dir3%BuildDate%\filename*.zip .
```

Output from Jenkins console:

```
c:\jenkins\workspace\my_build_job_name>copy \\Network_drive\dir1\dir2\dir3\ \filename*.zip .
\\Network_drive\dir1\dir2\dir3\ \filename*.zip
The system cannot find the path specified. 0 file(s) copied

c:\jenkins\workspace\my_build_job_name>exit 1
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Notifying upstream projects of job completion Finished: FAILURE*
```

Note: We have a Windows/Linux mixed environment. Whenever we want to run shell scripts, we use Cygwin, batch should directly run.

Comment: This looks like it should work.  How are you triggering the build?  Perhaps you have a typo in your parameter?

Comment: You are sure the environment variable is not accidentally reset? Does the parameter work in the original job? Why? Perhaps some _printf debugging_ (i.e., **echo %BuildDate%**) may reveal were things go wrong.

Comment: @DanielOmoto: I do not have typo in the parameter, I just double checked. We are running it on windows 7 server-data center.

Comment: @StefanHanke:: I do have the same doubt like the variable is getting reset somewhere. But don't know how to troubleshoot it. However, it runs completely fine for the original job.

Comment: The original job works, so the error must have been introduced by some change the job went through. You could try to clone the original job again, and then modify it one-by-one until it either works as expected or runs into the same error. Also, you could try to emulate every step the job does manually in a cmd window.

Comment: This is fixed!!! It was parameter issue. The parameters were not being fed if you don't kick the build from the very first node. I still wonder why it was not being fed. But kicking the build from the very first upstream project solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it turned out that one of the parameters was not populating due to hitting "rebuild last". Re-running the whole pipeline did it work. I still wonder why it was not populating but its all hood now!!!